# AuthComponent storage set as Memory

Tags: cakephp, memory, storage, cakephp-3.0

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
   'storage' => 'Memory',
```

What mean it is saved in Memory ? So where? RAM ? I am search to find it and clear.

Comment: `Storage class to use for persisting user record. When using stateless authenticator you should set this to Memory` so I think it stores it nowhere as it's stateless.

Comment: Read the docs and check the source? https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Auth/Storage/MemoryStorage.php

Answer (score 2):

Compare the auth [session storage class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Auth/Storage/SessionStorage.php):

```
/**
 * Read user record from session.
 *
 * @return array|null User record if available else null.
 */
public function read()
{
    if ($this->_user !== null) {
        return $this->_user ?: null;
    }
    $this->_user = $this->_session->read($this->_config['key']) ?: false;
    return $this->_user;
}

/**
 * Write user record to session.
 *
 * The session id is also renewed to help mitigate issues with session replays.
 *
 * @param array|\ArrayAccess $user User record.
 * @return void
 */
public function write($user)
{
    $this->_user = $user;
    $this->_session->renew();
    $this->_session->write($this->_config['key'], $user);
}
```

To the auth [memory storage class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Auth/Storage/MemoryStorage.php):

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function read()
{
    return $this->_user;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function write($user)
{
    $this->_user = $user;
}
```

Whereas the session storage class (and probably all other 3rd party implementations) look to find/store the data *somewhere*, the memory storage class only stores/retrieves information from it's own `_user` property.

As such, the data stored in the Memory storage class persists only for the life of the (http) request, the very next http request will have no auth credentials and will need, if relevant, to provide auth credentials again. This class of storage is applicable to stateless Auth systems, as [indicated in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-stateless-authentication-systems):

> For stateless authenticators the storage config should be set to Memory so that AuthComponent does not use session to store user record.